# Cannot run the following code

Tags: c++

I am trying the lean mean C++ option parser and I tried the example

```
#include <iostream>
 #include "optionparser.h"

 enum  optionIndex { UNKNOWN, HELP, PLUS };

 const option::Descriptor usage[] =
 {
  {UNKNOWN, 0,"" , ""    ,option::Arg::None, "USAGE: example [options]\n\n"
                                             "Options:" },
  {HELP,    0,"" , "help",option::Arg::None, "  --help  \tPrint usage and exit." },
  {PLUS,    0,"p", "plus",option::Arg::None, "  --plus, -p  \tIncrement count." },
  {UNKNOWN, 0,"" ,  ""   ,option::Arg::None, "\nExamples:\n"
                                             "  example --unknown -- --this_is_no_option\n"
                                             "  example -unk --plus -ppp file1 file2\n" },
  {0,0,0,0,0,0}
 };

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   argc-=(argc>0); argv+=(argc>0);              // skip program name argv[0] if present
   option::Stats  stats(usage, argc, argv);    
   option::Option options[stats.options_max], buffer[stats.buffer_max]; //------------Error Comes here-----------------------
   option::Parser parse(usage, argc, argv, options, buffer);

   if (parse.error())
     return 1;

   if (options[HELP] || argc == 0) {
     option::printUsage(std::cout, usage);
     return 0;
   }

   std::cout << "--plus count: " <<
     options[PLUS].count() << "\n";

   for (option::Option* opt = options[UNKNOWN]; opt; opt = opt->next())
     std::cout << "Unknown option: " << opt->name << "\n";

   for (int i = 0; i < parse.nonOptionsCount(); ++i)
     std::cout << "Non-option #" << i << ": " << parse.nonOption(i) << "\n";
 }
```

However the get the errors

Error   1   error C2057: expected constant expression
Error   2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
Error   3   error C2133: 'options' : unknown size
Error   4   error C2133: 'buffer' : unknown size

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Comment: Arrays need a compile-time constant as the size. The documentation doesn't suggest it is.

Comment: What lines of the code do the errors correspond to?

Comment: The error occurs at `option::Option options[stats.options_max], buffer[stats.buffer_max];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option::Option options[stats.options_max], buffer[stats.buffer_max];`

Arrays must have size known at compile time. Use vectors intsead.

`vector<option::Option> options(stats.options_max), buffer(stats.buffer_max);`

Comment: Error 1 error C2664: 'option::Parser::Parser(const option::Descriptor [],int,const char **,option::Option [],option::Option [],int,bool,int)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char *[]' to 'const char **'

Comment: @Rajeshwar, Parameter 3 is where you pass `argv`. That has absolutely nothing to do with this change. If the function doesn't change anything, it should have been marked as `const char * const *`, though, which can't be helped.